# Devise after sign up path with an additional reddirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After user registration, user lands on `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` in `RegistrationsController`.

This path leads user to screen that needs to be shown. If invited in a group, the user will after registration land on a group, if user is invited in community it will land on the community, etc.
The redirect path is built via the `store_location_for` method.

**My question is**, how can I make an additional redirect before that?

My goal is to have a Wellcome screen and then at the button continue to redirect to lading screen that can be group or community.

Comment: You can either squirrel away the stored location in the session or pass it as along as a URI encoded query parameter in the first redirect.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is override `after_signup_path_for` method:

```
def store_location_for
  session[:location] = ...your location
end

def after_signup_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session[:location].present? ? redirect_to session[:location] : super
end
```